# jQuery Aristo theme removes tooltips' style

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-theme, jquery-ui-tooltip

## Situation

---

I am using [Aristo](https://github.com/taitems/Aristo-jQuery-UI-Theme) as my jQuery UI theme. It works just fine, but when it comes to display tooltips, they cover 100% of the page width.

I don't have this particular issue with other themes. So I inspected `Aristo.css` in which I didn't find anything related to the tooltip's width unfortunately.

Here is how I initialize the jQuery tooltips:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
}).tooltip();
```

## Updates

---

### 07.04

It appears that Aristo completely removes style for the jQuery tooltip only. The default tooltips are working fine.

Hence the tooltip get a default width of `100%`, no padding also.

### 07.05

[image: Image showing the issue]

Comment: Which version of jQuery UI are you using? I don't think Aristo is the problem here, check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/6ukNz/ and you can see the tooltip is normal. If you can, please post the link to your site or create a fiddle.

Comment: I am also using jQuery 1.9.1 and jQuery UI 1.9.2. Even tried both 1.10.x but didn't change a bit.

Comment: Ok could you send link to your test or create a fiddle then?

Comment: Well, this is why it is such a difficult bug to fix. I can't replicate it elsewhere than my project, which I can't link. The *default* jQuery UI themes work fine, only Aristo does it bad :/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the problem, Aristo theme doesn't remove tooltip's styles. Actually it doesn't provide css style for tooltip, that's why the style is missing.

So you should at least add this to your css file then:

```
.ui-tooltip {
    padding: 8px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    max-width: 300px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #aaa;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #aaa;
}
body .ui-tooltip {
    border-width: 2px;
}
/* Copied from jQuery UI css */
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: I guess I was too stupid to think of this :/. Add to this the fact that I thought the style was dynamically set with JavaSCript. Happy bounty ;].

Comment: Yes that could be the case so I also traced down jQuery UI docs about tooltips and the style can only be set during initialize time. Cheers ;)